# Connecting raspberry pi with ev3 using i2c

Tags: i2c, arduino

Recently, I have been trying to build a project where I need to connect an ev3 to a raspberry pi. I have decided doing it by i2c after reading (and successfully replicating) an article about connecting an ev3 to arduino by i2c https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/connecting-ev3-arduino/.  However, after setting it up with raspberry pi, I realized a huge problem that I am facing, both of these devices acted as masters and I could not get them to connect to each other.

So, I decided to use an Arduino between those two which transports the data that it receives to the other device, which I couldn't get working. I have no idea how to get it working anyways, it was just a hopeless try.

Is such a project possible or should I just give up? If I should, what type of communication do you suggest that I use?

If you know any way of putting the Raspberry Pi into the slave mode, I would really appreciate if you share it.

Comment: I'm using TCP over USB to connect to my EV3.  It allows me to ssh into EV3, it's a level I feel more comfortable with than i2c.

Comment: What exactly is an ev3

Comment: What exactly did you "successfully replicate"?

Comment: Lego Mindstorms EV3.

Answer (score 1):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) has limited support for the Pi to act as an I2C slave.

See http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bsc_i2c

That example is Python.

Note that when acting as a slave device you need to use GPIO 18 (SDA) and GPIO 19 (SCL).  You also need to fit external pull-ups to 3V3.  For reference the ones on GPIO 2/3 are 1k8 pull-ups to 3V3.

If you look through the documentation you will see several examples in C, Python, and the command line ([pigs](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html)).

It is what it is - that means you will have to work around its limitations or find another solution.

See my [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1061380) for background information and a usage example.

Comment: Wow, thanks man, you literally saved my life, though I need to ask, can I connect 43 K to 4.7 V since that worked with arduino. Sorry for the noob question, I am quite new to electronics.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by 43 K to 4.7 V.  Remember ALL the Pi GPIO are only tolerant to a voltage between 0 and 3.3V.  Anything outside those limits risks damaging the GPIO and the Pi.